# PowerBI Lookupvalue with mutiple matches

Tags: powerbi

I have the below two tables.

TABLE 1

| Trip # | Delivery Location |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 | A6 |
| 0002 | E8 |
| 0002 | A6 |
| 0003 | C9 |

TABLE 2

| Trip # | Delivery Location |
| --- | --- |
| 0001 |  |
| 0002 |  |
| 0003 |  |

I need to populate TABLE 2, Delivery Location, with the FIRST MATCH from Table 1.

I have tried LOOKUPVALUE but get an error as there are multiple possible matches sometimes.

I need to do this at the DAX level as a calculated column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the first location from `TABLE 1`, then `TABLE 1` needs another column to help determine the order of the rows. The following will work, but currently returns `A6` for `0002`.

```
Delivery Location = 
  var thisTrip = [Trip #]
  return CALCULATE(
    MIN('TABLE 1'[Delivery Location]), 
    TOPN(1, FILTER('TABLE 1', 'TABLE 1'[Trip #] = thisTrip))
  )
```

Comment: Thanks! Let me test this on my bulk data and see how we go.